# When to use !() or != when if not null

Tags: c#, coding-style

Whilst refactoring code I changed the all the if not null conditions to follow the majority convention in my code of

```
if (!(foo == null))
```

instead of

```
if (foo != null)
```

Is there any advantage in either statement?

Is there any advantage in either statement in c#?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I find the second one more readable.

Apart from that, there is no difference.

It is more important to pick a convention with your team and stick to it within any one particular codebase.

Comment: And in addition when you are reading code in the first scenario you can see to actions (equals and not) but in the second one it's more "reading friendly" and you perceive like single action.

Comment: @Oded: Agree "second one (*slightly*) more readable" relatively to the first one, but it's, IMHO, WAY too unreadable in light of the reasons in and relative to the alternative suggestion in my Answer dated 12/21/17 below.  Also, often "conventions", that may have been perfectly fine based on the knowledge and situations at the time, are totally inadequate in light of new knowledge and/or situations.

Comment: @Tom I disagree, I think your answer needs more abstraction not a change from `!` to `false.equals()`

Comment: @ChrisRudd: Come on, man.  You know that's besides the point I'm making.  That's just one example, there could easily be almost infinite other examples where that's a perfectly appropriate Expression form (without converting to a single Method Call).  Sure, *every* expression *could* ultimately be reduced to a single Method Call and eventually a single Operator Expression, but I think most would find the typing, (in many cases) performance and more importantly, readability costs not worth it.  Btw, I changed `false.equals(...)` to `(false == ...)`.

Answer (score 10):

Assuming you don't have broken `==` / `!=` operator overloads, I'd just use the second form for the benefit of simplicity / readability. If you *do* have broken overloads such that there's a semantic difference between the two, then I'd suggest fixing those overloads :)

In the rare case where `foo == null` is a clearer indication of something, I'd probably refactor it to use a local variable:

```
bool somethingIsMissing = foo == null;
if (!somethingIsMissing)
{
    ...
}
```

Parentheses round the `foo == null` are now optional - use or don't, according to taste. The main thing is that you can use the variable name to make the semantic meaning *really clear*.

Comment: IMHO, still WAY too unreadable in light of the reasons in and relative to the alternative suggestion in my Answer dated 12/21/17 below.

Comment: @Tom: I think we'll have to agree to disagree. I'd rather use the common, idiomatic approach that won't surprise any developers.

Comment: In `if(!a==b)`, what is evaluated first !a or == ?

Comment: @variable: It's equivalent to `(!a) == b` - see https://github.com/dotnet/csharpstandard/blob/draft-v6/standard/expressions.md#1242-operator-precedence-and-associativity. If both operands are `bool` though, I'd just rewrite it to `if (a != b)` for simplicity.

Answer (score 6):

normally `if (!(foo == null))` is used when you have more variables to considerate, for example

```
if (!(f1 == 'a' && f2 != 'b'))
```

sometimes **is just easier this way** that transform everything to the opposite, specially when you using bitwise operators.

Comment: I'd probably use `if (f1 != 'a' || f2 == 'b')` to be clearer in that case.

Comment: it's hard when you have a big chain and specially with flags :-/ it's more "readable" like `if(!( e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && (e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) == DataControlRowState.Edit))` no? like `if is not a DataRow or Edit type...`

Comment: That's the sort of situation where I'd probably separate out the condition into a local variable with a meaningful name.

Comment: You should refactor something like that example to a meaningful boolean method.

Comment: more variables, more memory, more characters, more lines :) machine understands it very well... It all goes for the developer task ... mine, I guess it's the hard one :/

Answer (score 5):

The first uses two operators, the second uses one. So technically, the second one is simpler.

Comment: but the recommended implementation of operator `!=` is `return !(a == b)`. So it does under the hood the same.

Comment: This is like saying a motorcycle is easier to drive than a car, because it has fewer wheels.

Answer (score 4):

The only place where i would use `!(a == b)` would within the operator implementation of `!=` like this way:

```
public static bool operator != (MyType a, MyType b)
{
    return !(a == b);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, there is no difference, the compiler will optimize the code anyway. But I would prefer `if(foo != null)`. Less parentheses and easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

My prefered one is the second one, as it is a bit more legible than the the first.

They make no difference so it is just a matter of choice for you.

However, if you have lots of other variables in your if clause, the first may be the one to use.

Your choice in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Readability is key, so when you're using an equality operator you should put the != there to make it more clear.  But when the comparison gets more complicated there are situations where the other version can be better

`if ( (a != b) and (a != c) )` is more clear than `if (!( (a == b) or (a == c) ))`.  However the `if !()` format is better when you have functions that return boolean values like `if !(a.valid())` or `if !( String.IsNullOrEmpty(a) )`

Also if your equality expression gets particularly complex that can also hurt readability, at which point it's better to move the test(s) to a function with a clear name like `if !( this.AllSettingsValid() )`

Answer (score 0):

In C# 8 you can now write "where value is something"

`if (value is { })`

It also goes well with the nullable refence feature that will be turned on in 2021 for everything.

Answer (score 0):

There is not such a difference, by using `if (!(foo == null))`, code optimization might be violated since **it has to verify the condition first and then reverse it**.

On another side, `if (foo != null)` **will iterate condition only once**. Hence you can say, `if (foo != null)` is a more optimized way.

Answer (score -1):

Since, the first form uses 2 vs. 1 C# Operators, it *might* compile to more CIL code albeit, in most use cases most would encounter, it probably won't make a significant code size or performance difference.

What IS likely to make a significant difference is readability and therefore chance of errors when writing / modifying.  I would (and you Sheldons may want to cover your eyes now) avoid the use of the "!" Operator com-PLETELY.  "Gasp!  My - WORD!"  Yes, I said it.  And I MEANT IT!  With a PASSION!  It's too easy to miss as it's often next to a similar-looking punctuation character (i.e. "(" or "||") on its left and a similar-looking Identifier letter (i.e. "l" or "I") on its right.  And missing it could have MAJOR consequences, as it would mean you think the code is doing the exact OPPOSITE of what it's actually doing!  And it could also be significantly more likely to be missed by dyslexics making it potentially a disability rights issue protected by the ADA.

Consider the following very likely example:

```
   if (!IsIisServerConnected)
   if (IsOfflineMode || !(IsIisLocalServerConnected || IsIisCloudServerConnected))
```

I would instead write the following:

```
   if (false == IsIisServerConnected)

   if 
   (
     IsOfflineMode 
     || 
     (
       false ==
       (
         IsIisLocalServerConnected 
         || IsIisCloudServerConnected
       )
     )
   )
```

Or in your case:

```
   if (false == (foo == null))
```

Remember that C (the language that C#, C++, JavaScript, Java and numerous other currently popular languages *ultimately* inherited their *basic* syntax from) was created at a time when Punch Cards were still common.  With modern day CPUs, RAM, monitors and IDE's (that "false.Equals(?)" snippet could be generated with a custom Keyboard Shortcut), for most people for most apps, readability is much, Much, MUCH (did I mention "much"?) more important than saving a few code characters.

P.S. You could also add a Extension Method to the `Boolean` Struct calling it, oh, I don't know, `Not`! ;D  So you could write:

```
if (IsIisServerConnected.Not())
if ((foo == null).Not())
```

Comment: While it's on the cusp, I would argue that your  `if ( IsOfflineMode || !(IsIisLocalServerConnected || IsIisCloudServerConnected) )` is unclear not because of the use of `!` but because you're doing too many checks without abstraction.  It would be more clear if encapsulated in a function such as `if ( !(this.Connected()) )` or `if ( this.NotConnected() )`

Comment: @ChrisRudd: Come on, man.  You know that's besides the point I'm making.  That's just one example, there could easily be almost infinite other examples where that's a perfectly appropriate Expression form (without converting to a single Method Call).  Sure, *every* expression *could* ultimately be reduced to a single Method Call and eventually a single Operator Expression, but I think most would find the typing, (in many cases) performance and more importantly, readability costs not worth it.  Btw, I changed `false.equals(...)` to `(false == ...)`.

Comment: it's not about how many other examples there are, the fundamental core of your comment is about READABILITY and switching to "not"s half way through a check (regardless of whether it's done via ! or false.equals) is confusing to read. It took me about 2 minutes of study to figure out what your check was actually doing (initially it seems to contradict itself). If you can't tell what an *If ()* is doing with about 5 seconds, then it needs to be abstracted out to something more self explanatory. And that's ignoring that "false.equals" innately appears paradoxical, which harms readability.

Comment: As for whether *If (foo != null)* is less clear than *If (isNull(foo) == False)*, that's debatable.  Though I would point out that Verbosity does not equal Clarity.  And so you're not just taking my word for it I encourage you to see these  [Clarity over Verbosity](https://dev.to/mudasobwa/clarity-over-verbosity-everywhere-clp) and [An English Professor's take on readable code](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZsHMHukIlJY)

Comment: Upon further review the Clarity over Verbosity link wasn't very useful (mostly just angry ranting), but the youtube one is definitely worth your time.  And for the record you're not categorically wrong.  I think you've found an underused approach that was useful in the situation where you discovered it.  The fault comes when you try to blindly apply it universally rather than only where appropriate.  As a peace offering I present you with my reformatted version of your example, I hope it meets your approval [If Reformatted](http://oneclickpaste.com/32330/)